# Creating an anonymous django session

Tags: django, django-sessions

In my attempts to learn django, I've been trying to make a clone of `dayscore.net`. Meaning that, I want to make the site using django, this does not refer to a `git clone` or a `hg clone` If you take a look, every time a new user comes to dayscore, you get a unique session, with a special hash code. How would you achieve something like this using django?

Comment: Django sessions does exactly the same thing. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/).

Answer (score 2):

1) As was pointed in the comment to your question Django applies session ID to any request if you have enabled Session middleware.

2) In case you still want to generate session id yourself you can create middleware where on `process_request` you'll create hash value and add it to sessions.

**middleware.py**

```
import uuid

class AnonHashMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        """
        If user is not authenticated (anonymous) we set session hashcode
        uuid4 hex
        """
        if not request.user.is_authenticated() and \
                'hashcode' not in request.session:
            request.session['hashcode'] = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

**Pros**

- No matter what page of the site user comes in if he is anonymous without hashcode he'll get hashcode generated for him.

**Cons**

- Middleware will be applied for each request coming to the server just like all other middlewares.

Comment: No, I would like to recreate it, using django only.

Comment: make it precise in your question you want to make such behavior and not just clone (like `wget -r` the site)

Comment: I thought it was clear because you talk about things like a 'facebook clone' and a 'hackernews clone', so I thought this would not cause confusion. I mean, when was the last time you wanted to clone an actual site?

Comment: I helped with cloning of the site about 1 week ago for one person willing to learn web development so it wasn't clear for me. Maybe I looked at your question from that perspective

Comment: Besides I have updated the answer considering your clarification

Comment: I think the hashcode should be generated when there's no hashcode specified in the URL. I would make a view for `/` URL, which redirect the user to the main view, like what `dayscore.net` does.

Comment: What if the user comes on the page different from `/`? If applying hashcode is implemented in middleware it will give a hashcode don't matter which page of the site user comes which I think is pretty convenient and user-friendly. On the other side your suggestion to use view instead of middleware reduces number of middlewares